# Unique char pair in two strings

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, algorithm

So I need some help with an exercise, I'm stuck! Go easy on me, I'm fairly new to this. The exercise goes as follows:

> Given two char arrays of equal lengths, determine if each character from the first array can be replaced uniquely with a character from the second one so that both arrays are equal. Display the character pairs between the two arrays.

Example 1: 
Given the following input: `aab` and `ttd`, the console will display:

```
True
a => t
b => d
```

Example 2: 
Given the following input: `aba` and `ttd`, the console will display:

```
False
```

In the second example the answer is `False` because there is no unique replacer for character `a`: both `t` and `d` correspond.

I have been busting my head with this and honestly I feel like I cannot even think straight anymore. Tweaked the code so many times already that I almost don't understand it anymore. It still passes the first test though, but seems to keep failing a test with a longer string input. For example with the inputs: `ala bala portocala` and `cuc dcuc efghijcuc`, the console displays `True` and then the pairs, which is not right. Below you have my POS code, any advice is welcome.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string a = Console.ReadLine();
        string b = Console.ReadLine();

        string one = string.Empty;
        string two = string.Empty;

        bool res = false;
        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++) 
        {
            if (!one.Contains(a[i].ToString()))
            {
                if (!two.Contains(b[i].ToString())) 
                {
                    one += a[i];
                    two += b[i];
                }
            }
        }

        char[] firstPhrase = new char[one.Length];
        char[] scndPhrase = new char[two.Length];

        for(int i = 0; i < one.Length; i++) 
        {
            bool temp = false;
            for(int j = 0; j < two.Length; j++) 
            {
                if(firstPhrase[j] != one[i]) 
                {
                    for(int k = 0; k < scndPhrase.Length; k++) 
                    {
                        if(scndPhrase[j] == two[i]) { res = true; break; }

                    }
                    if(res == true) { break; }
                    else { continue; }
                }
                if(firstPhrase[j] == one[i]) 
                {
                    if (scndPhrase[j] == two[i]) { temp = true; continue; }
                    else { res = true; break; }
                }

            }
            if(temp == false) 
            {
                firstPhrase[count] = one[i];
                scndPhrase[count] = two[i];
                count++;
            }
            if(res == true) { break; }
        }


        if (res == true)
            Console.WriteLine(res);
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(!res);
            for (int i = 0; i < firstPhrase.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{firstPhrase[i]} => {scndPhrase[i]}");
            }
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
```

I look forward to your critique and I wish you all a Happy Easter!

**Edit**: forgot to mention, so so sorry guys. The tests don't allow the use of LINQ or any other directives, LINQ was actually the first thing I wanted to try.

Comment: Is it possible that you understood the assignment incorrectly? Because it says at the end: " so that both arrays are equal" and replacing a with t and b with d in the first example gives the following to arrays which are not equal: ttd, aab?

Comment: Did you teacher gave this as the first test that needs to pass?

Comment: Hey Oguz, yeah I think something might've gotten lost in translation. Even in the native language it is phrased a bit oddly. You don't actually have to replace the characters, the replacement is hypothetical. The point is to determine whether each character can have a unique replacer in the other array, and then to map those unique replacers.

Comment: And no, the first test is with the following inputs: "ala bala portocala" and  "cuc dcuc efghficuc", and the code passes it. Doesn't get past the second one though..

Comment: is it "cuc dcuc efghficuc" or "cuc dcuc efghficuc"

Comment: The one that passes has the second input as "cuc dcuc efghficuc", and the one that fails is  "cuc dcuc efghijcuc"

Comment: I Upvoted both answers since they solve the problem both. 15 rep is needed for the vote to be directly seen I think.

Comment: What is the expected output for `"ab"`, `"tt"`?  I assume it would be false, right?

Comment: @Brian that is not how I understood this question, "characters from first array can be replaced uniquely with a character from the second one". Not the other way around. In "ab" "tt" the "a" will be mapped to "t" and the "b" will also be mapped to "t". If you expand your case like "aba" "ttk" it will be False, because "a" would be mapped to "t" and also to "k".

Comment: @Goodies Well, that is exactly why I was asking, because the wording of the problem is ambiguous to me-- it says *"determine if each character from the first array can be replaced uniquely with a character from the second"*.  If `a` is replaced with `t` and `b` is *also* replaced with `t` then you could argue that isn't a unique replacement.  For the  Example 2 case ("aba", "ttk"), it contains violations in both directions, but they only cite one of them.  But then, you only need one violation to cause the result to be false.  So clarification is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using only System namespace.

The important part here is to change the characters in both arrays to tokens first.

This means, for "ala bala portocala" we will have:

```
{ 0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 5, 8, 0, 1, 0 }
```

So whenever a new character (which has not appeared before) is found, we increment the number by 1.

And you can see that this works well to evaluate if the two char arrays are a match in terms of this interesting perspective.

```
static int[] Tokenize(char[] array)
{
    int length = array.Length;
    int[] distinctArray = new int[length];
    int offset = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        bool appearedBefore = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            if (array[j] == array[i])
            {
                appearedBefore = true;
                distinctArray[i] = distinctArray[j];
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!appearedBefore)
        {
            distinctArray[i] = offset;
            offset++;
        }
    }
    return distinctArray;
}
```

Then the test method:

```
static void Test(char[] array1, char[] array2)
{
    Console.WriteLine("[{0}] VS [{1}]", new string(array1), new string(array2));

    int[] array1Tokenized = Tokenize(array1);
    int[] array2Tokenized = Tokenize(array2);

    for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++)
    {
        if (array1Tokenized[i] != array2Tokenized[i])
        {
            Console.WriteLine("False");
            return;
        }
    }

    Console.Write("True");
    for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++)
    {
        bool appearedBefore = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            if (array1[j] == array1[i])
            {
                appearedBefore = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!appearedBefore && array1[i] != array2[i])
        {
            Console.Write(" {0} => {1}", array1[i], array2[i]);
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

And the results:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Test("ala bala portocala".ToCharArray(), "cuc dcuc efghijcuc".ToCharArray());

    Test("ala bala portocala".ToCharArray(), "cuc dcuc efghfjcuc".ToCharArray());

    Test("aab".ToCharArray(), "ttd".ToCharArray());
}
```

Output:

```
[ala bala portocala] VS [cuc dcuc efghijcuc]
False

[ala bala portocala] VS [cuc dcuc efghfjcuc]
True a => c l => u b => d p => e o => f r => g t => h c => j

[aab] VS [ttd]
True a => t b => d
```

Comment: Can definitely learn a lot from your solution, thank you so much for taking your time to help me out! I appreciate all comments and solutions. Stay safe and I wish you a great evening!

Comment: Can be made simpler I guess. A single pass o(log n)  Solution seems possible

Answer (score 2):

Here is a short solution using only the `System` namespace.  Basically all we need to do is loop through the strings once in parallel, and for each position check whether the characters from each string are mapped to each other.  There are three cases:

1. The characters have not been mapped before, in which case we map them to each other;
2. The characters are already mapped to each other, in which case we keep going;
3. Either character is already mapped, but not to the other character, in which case there is not a valid solution so we return null.

To keep track of the mappings we use two parallel arrays, `mappings` and `reverseMappings`.  Since characters are just numbers, we can use the value of the first character as an index into the mapping array and set the value equal to the second character.  Same thing for the reverse mapping, but with the opposite characters.  (This will work as long as the mapping arrays are large enough to handle every possible character value we expect.  For ASCII, 128 is the max size needed.  For Unicode it would need to be 65536.)  As we go, we keep a count of how many pairs we've seen so far.  This is needed so that we know how big to make the return array (an n-by-2 array of arrays), which will contain the actual character pairings required for the output.  We construct that by scanning through the mapping array once, looking for all mappings that have a non-zero value.

```
public char[][] GetCharacterMappings(string s1, string s2)
{
    if (s1 == null || s2 == null || s1.Length != s2.Length) return null;

    // I'm assuming the inputs can only be in the ASCII character set;
    // If they can have any Unicode character, make this value larger (e.g. 65536) 
    const int maxCharValue = 128;
    char[] mappings = new char[maxCharValue];
    char[] reverseMappings = new char[maxCharValue];
    int pairCount = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < s1.Length; i++)
    {
        char c1 = s1[i];
        char c2 = s2[i];

        if (mappings[c1] == 0 && reverseMappings[c2] == 0)
        {
            // these characters have not been mapped before
            mappings[c1] = c2;
            reverseMappings[c2] = c1;
            pairCount++;
        }
        else if (mappings[c1] != c2 || reverseMappings[c2] != c1)
        {
            // either character is already mapped to some other character
            return null;
        }
    }

    char[][] pairs = new char[pairCount][];
    int p = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < maxCharValue; i++)
    {
        if (mappings[i] != 0)
            pairs[p++] = new char[] { (char)i, mappings[i] };
    }

    return pairs;
}
```

The output routine just checks whether the pairings are null, and if not, dumps them all out:

```
public void WriteResult(char[][] pairs)
{
    Console.WriteLine(pairs != null);
    if (pairs != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < pairs.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(pairs[i][0] + " => " + pairs[i][1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/lBHKUY

Comment: @Downvoter, care to comment on how I can improve my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a .NET dictionary. When below function returns null, there is no consistent mapping. When it returns a dictionary, its content will be the mapping. I compiled this, I did NOT test it..

```
public static Dictionary<char, char> BuildMapping(string s1, string s2)
{
    if (s1.Length != s2.Length) return null;
    Dictionary<char, char> result= new Dictionary<char, char>();
    for (int i = 0; i < s2.Length; i++)
    {
        if (result.ContainsKey(s1[i]))
            if (result[s1[i]] == s2[i]) continue;
            else return null;
        result[s1[i]] = s2[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for your answer. Edited the original post, so sorry. The tests don't allow the use of any other directives than System.

Comment: Well.. maybe this is a good sub-assignment, then: implement a class that stores a mapping for char-char and call it "Dictionary". By the way.. tell your teacher no programmers today start out with zero libs. When you want to learn C#, additional knowledge of .net is *essential*. You dont have to acknowledge my answer, please upvote it.. thx

Comment: good point, I was surprised as well that they don't allow the use of other libs. This stage is focused on algorithmic assignments, my guess is that they don't allow the use of other directives because it would make the tasks too easy. Thank you for the suggestion though, I'll give it a go this evening and see how it turns out. Really appreciate your input.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with LINQ:

```
var result = str1.Zip(str2, (f, s) =>  f.ToString() + s.ToString())
                 .GroupBy(c => c[0])
                 .Where(c => c.Select(d => d[1]).Distinct()
                 .Skip(1).Any()).Any() ? false : true;
```

All that you need to run this, is just adding `using System.Linq` to your using directives.

You can see the result online here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/OF2cnO

Comment: So sorry, forgot to mention it in the original post, edited it now. The test doesn't allow the use of anything else than System. Linq would've been my first try.

Comment: @DaveLancaster What's your mean? You can simply add `using System.Linq` to your using directives, it doesn't require anything special, the .NET is supporting it by default.

Comment: The platform doesn't allow the use of Linq or any other directives than System, tried it with Linq at first but the platform refused to compile it because of it.

Comment: @DaveLancaster What's the platform that you are testing this against?

Comment: The platform is called Juniormind, some sort of recruitment startup that provides courses and training. Not a well-known one like Exercism or CodeWars.

Comment: Looks great Salah ! Dave wont upvote it,but  I will.. and test it.. you are using some features of Linq I was not aware of. Interesting answer.

Comment: Hey but I did upvote it.. Don't have enough reputation yet though so it doesn't get displayed

Comment: Ah ok Dave, did not know that.. btw  @Salah you gotta test for unequal length strings, other cases seem to yield a correct true/false result ! It does not give the mapping itself .. maybe it could it be possible to store the result mapping underways ?